# Using jackson annotation to output child without nested format

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have two class.

```
Class A{
    B b;
}
Class B{
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

I am getting this.

```
{"b":
     {"name":name}
}
```

Is there a way to get the following output in my rest api.

```
{"b":name}
```

Comment: Yes, create a dedicated class that matches the desired JSON, e.g. `class C { String b; }` and map your A class to the C class before converting to JSON, e.g. `C c = new C(); c.b = a.b.name; return c;`.

Comment: just return only `Class B`